# RTL ActionBar with Min-SDK 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I create `DrawerLayout` and `Min-Sdk` is 11(Also Can't change `Min-Sdk`). I need change `ActionBar` to *RTL* and change the menu Icon. All solution I found need `Min-Sdk` 17. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Can I use [ActionBarRTLizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4PDS.png) in Eclipse project and ActionBarRTLizer work in `Sdk-11`?

how import ActionBarRTLizer in project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend to use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of ActionBar ([ActionBarRTlize](https://github.com/semsamot/ActionBarRTLizer) is relatively old repository). By using Toolbar you can easily customize it (RTL or what ever your want).

Here is a snippet of my recent toolbar may help you:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/gray_lighter"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <!--selectableItemBackgroundBorderless-->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/icon_toolbar_back"
                style="@style/IconFont.XLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_toolbar"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:minWidth="56dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_toolbar_title"
                style="@style/Textview.Dark.MediumLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_toolbar_back"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And one thing to mention don't forget to change theme to `NoActionBar`:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this need API 16 and higher, not work in API 11

Comment: This is works. Did you change language at runtime? What do you mean by not work? I use this in my recent project.

Comment: Add support RTL flag in manifest and also create RTL layout if you have multiple languages.